# Crossfade Keyframe Percentages Algorithm

Tags: html, algorithm, css

I found this on a website, but I'm not sure I understand it correctly...Everytime I try it doesn't work out. Can someone elaborate on this for me?

**I have 4 images that I'm trying to rotate every 12 seconds, with a 1 second animation.**

> He proposes the following algorithm to determine the percentages and
>   timings:
>
> For "n" images You must define: a=presentation time for one image
>   b=duration for cross fading Total animation-duration is of course
>   t=(a+b)*n
>
> animation-delay = t/n or = a+b
>
> Percentage for keyframes:
>
> 1. 0%
> 2. a/t*100%
> 3. (a+b)/t*100% = 1/n*100%
> 4. 100%-(b/t*100%)
> 5. 100%

You can find this here:
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Thank you very much.

```
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% { opacity: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease; }
  23% { opacity: 0;
  animation-timing-function: ease; }
  25% { opacity: 0;
  animation-timing-function: ease; }
  33% { opacity: 0;
  animation-timing-function: ease; }
  100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/joelssk/1jLk06as/4/

Comment: In your case `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `n = 4`, and `t = 12`, right? It's not that hard to see that your percentages do not match with those values...

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele number 3 is throwing me off..can you elaborate?

Comment: `animation-delay` only affects the *start* of the animation, so once those delays hit their timer they will start to animate at the same time

Comment: Oh, I see that I misunderstood, based on your jsfiddle.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele basically...If I can change this to my times http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbQaQq

Comment: For more than one iteration, the bradshawenterprises code works fine as-is on Firefox, but on Chrome it requires "will-change: opacity;" on the affected elements, otherwise the delays will get out of sync on subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing magical about the percentages. If you have 4 images that need to rotate, each of them showing 11 seconds before a 1-second transition period, then how does that look?

In the below sketch, `X` is visible, `_` is invisible and `<` and `>` are fade in and fade out, respectively.

```
time  0           12          24          36
img1  XXXXXXXXXXX>___________________________________<
img2  ___________<XXXXXXXXXXX>________________________
img3  _______________________<XXXXXXXXXXX>____________
img4  ___________________________________<XXXXXXXXXXX>
```

If we look at the first image, what are the key frames, i.e., when something has to happen? From `0` to `11` the image is visible. From `11` to `12` it's fading out. From `12` to `47` it's invisible. And from `47` to `48` it's fading in.

Your total time is `48` seconds, so these times translate to (on a scale from 
`0` to `100`):

- `[0, 23]`: visible
- `[23, 25]`: fade out
- `[25, 98]`: invisible
- `[98, 100]`: fade in

or, in terms of keyframes:

```
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease; }
  23% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease; }
  25% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease; }
  98% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease; }
  100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

---

Now, it is quite clear that all images follow the same pattern, they only start at different times. As you can see from the diagram, the delays should be `0`, `12`, `24`, and `36` seconds.

Comment: Wow, I really wish someone would have explained this to me way before. This is honestly my 3rd time posting this question with no proper answer..

Thank you so much as you have no idea how much this means to me.